# how to connect to SQL Server 2005 from Visual C++

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-c++, authentication

Can anybody help to understand how to connect from Visual C++ to SQL Server 2005?

i am developing an ISAPI dll using Visual C++ and i need to query the database to fetch a few details.  I tried to connect to the DB using `CDatabase`.  When I invoked the dll from a local system, it worked without any issues.  But when i access the dll from a remote system, it's throwing `Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGON`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This [Accessing SQL Server from a Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article give you the list of options you can use for SQL Server authentication. You can [change the Identity of ISAPI Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525338%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to meet the demand of SQL Server once you choose an SQL Server authentication method.

Comment: Sheng, your input was very userful.  I Impersonated the user and its working fine now.